# Parent and collection of child objects

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Say I have a `Customer` class and an `Invoice` class. `Customer` contains a `List<Invoice>` property called `Invoices`. Can this be filled with a single `Linq` statement? Or do I need to select customers first and then do a `foreach` on them to pull invoices later?

Something like:

```
(from customer in customers
 join invoice in invoices on customer.Id = invoice.CustomerId
 select <what>?
```

I can't select a customer there or the inner list isn't filled. Maybe a `group` instead?

Edit: This works. Just wondering if there was a different way

```
var customersWithInvoices =
   (from customer in customers
    let invoiceGroup = (from invoice in invoices where invoice.CustomerId == customer.Id select invoice).ToList()
    select new { customer, invoiceGroup }).ToList();

foreach (var obj in customersWithInvoices) {
   obj.customer.Invoices = obj.invoiceGroup;
   CustomerList.Add(obj.customer);
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks John I'll avoid tags in titles.

Comment: Are you talking about loading the Invoices from the database or executing queries against the collection ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if I wasn't clear. This is entirely coming from the database. Customers has a one to many relationship with Invoice. Wanted to load them together. Customer has all the properties of the table as well as the List<Invoice> in it. My edit above does what I need but it seemed to me I should have been able to select the data directly into the object.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Linq2SQL and not Entity framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. The work around is to use the `let` clause as shown in the Edit area of the OP:

```
var customersWithInvoices =
   (from customer in customers
    let invoiceGroup = (from invoice in invoices where invoice.CustomerId == customer.Id select invoice).ToList()
    select new { customer, invoiceGroup }).ToList();

foreach (var obj in customersWithInvoices) {
   obj.customer.Invoices = obj.invoiceGroup;
   CustomerList.Add(obj.customer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading from a database and are trying to load a collection you can use the `.Include()` method to explicitly load the collection. If you try to access the collection after your connection to the database has closed then you will recieve an error.

You should use the following:

```
using(var context = new ServiceContext())
{
  var customers = context.CustomerSet.Include(cust => cust.Invoices);
}
```